# Why there is a dead loop in the generated assembly for a Cortex-M interrupt handler?

Tags: gdb, microcontroller, cortex-m, thumb

I am learning the Cortex-M with the MDK uVision IDE. I wrote a simple `SysTick_Handler()` to replace the WEAK default `SysTick_Handler()` which is a simple dead loop.

My `SysTick_Handler()`:

[image]

The disassembly:

[image]

I am confused by the the highlighted assembly line. It is simply a dead loop.

Why is it there? Why the toolchain still generated it despite that I already overwrite the WEAK default implementation with my own `SysTick_Handler`?

I can still place a breakpoint at that line and **it can be hit**. And in that case, my code will never be executed.

But strange thing is, if I removed the breakpoint at that line, my code can  then be reached. How is that possible?

Comment: It looks like the disassembly is not properly matched to your function, i.e. off by a few bytes. It would also affect a breakpoint. A dead loop is often used as the default interrupt handler for non-maskable interrupts. So it is to be expected to find such code somewhere in your binary.

Comment: I agree with @Codo. It's quite possible that debugger got somehow confused with the WEAK reference and took the wrong address.

Comment: Yes I did keep the default implementation which is a dead loop. It is really misleading if a debugger can be confused this way...

Comment: disassemblers struggle to just disassemble the machine code, with optimize code there is no reason to ever assume that the high level and low level match up, much less rely on this.  Turn off the display of the high level language and you will be golden, well with an architecture like this that has half a chance at disassembling the machine code...If you want to accurately set a breakpoint dont use a debugger with a gui, figure it out yourself and use something like openocd with the telnet interface.

Comment: That looks like a different handler that is an infinite loop, the nop there to align it on a word boundary.

Comment: @old_timer That's very possible. Because I have several other dead loop handlers for other interrupt sources. And that very dead loop in question **can** be hit. I don't think a linker should still link a WEAK symbol in this case and a debugger to make such mistake. But it is listed under SysTick_handler though outside the curly brace, which makes it looks even more weird. Well a simple trial of the uVision IDE leads me to such strange result. I have to say it is disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Thanks to all the hints the community provided. I think I can explain it now.)

The dead loop is part of my `main()` function, which is like below. The `main()` function is just above my `SysTick_Handler` in the same C file.

```
int main (void)
{
    LED_Initialize();
    SysTick->VAL = 0x9000;                                                                                   
    //Start value for the sys Tick counter
    SysTick->LOAD = 0x9000;                                                                                  
    //Reload value 
    SysTick->CTRL = SYSTICK_INTERRUPT_ENABLE|SYSTICK_COUNT_ENABLE;  //Start and enable interrupt
    while(1)
    {
        ;  // <========= This is the dead loop I saw!
    }
}
```

To double confirm, I modified the while loop to below:

```
int main (void)
{
    volatile int32_t jj = 0;
    LED_Initialize();
    SysTick->VAL = 0x9000;                                                                                  //Start value for the sys Tick counter
    SysTick->LOAD = 0x9000;                                                                                 //Reload value 
    SysTick->CTRL = SYSTICK_INTERRUPT_ENABLE|SYSTICK_COUNT_ENABLE;  //Start and enable interrupt
    while(1)
    {
        ;
        jj+=0x12345; // <====== add some landmark value
    }
}
```

The generated code is like this now:

[image]

Though it is still placed under the `SysTick_Handler`. I place a break point there to check what's really going on:

[image]

[image]

The `R1` is the constant `0x12345`. The `R0` is the local variable `jj`. We can see the `R1` does contain the landmark value `0x12345`, which is added to `R0` (`jj`). So it must be part of my `while(1)` loop in the `main()`.

**So, the disassembly is correct. Only that the debugger failed to provide a correct interleaving between the source and the disassembly.**

And btw, remember to rebuild the target after modifying the code otherwise the uVision IDE debugger will not reflect the latest change....